# Is it better for a method to allow raising multiple types of exceptions or just one?

Tags: python, exception

My question is about the best (most 'pythonic' way of) exception handling in case when a method can raise two (or more) types of exceptions but their interpretation is the same from the view point of the caller.

Suppose I have a collection of named (name is string) objects. I want this collection to be able to return items by the index or by name.

```
class CollectionOfNamedItems:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self._dict = {item.name: item for item in items} 
        self._items = tuple(items)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, str):
            return = self._dict[item]  # may raise KeyError
        return self._items[item]  # may raise IndexError

# usage: collection['X'] or collection[1]
```

My question is this: depending on whether we access the item by index or by name, the `__getitem__` methods raises `IndexError` or `KeyError`. Is this a good way of raising exceptions? The caller of this method would have to catch these two types of exceptions. Or would it be better (more pythonic so to say) to catch `KeyError` and `IndexError` inside `__getitem__` and raise `ValueError` (or some other?) so that the caller can catch just one type of exception regardless of the type of argument passed.

```
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            if isinstance(item, str):
                return = self._dict[item]  # may raise KeyError
            return self._items[item]  # may raise IndexError
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            raise ValueError('invalid item')
```

On the other hand it seems that it is logical to throw `TypeError` when I call `collection[1.5]` or `collection[None]`. This is because I feel that the interpretation is different that the errors above.

I would appreciate any comment or idea on this topic.

Comment: This question might be more suited to the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you should always throw the *most specific exception* you can.  Even more important, don't throw exception types that are designed to mean something else.  In your case, `ValueError` clearly is the wrong exception type.

> depending on whether we access the item by index or by name, the `__getitem__` methods raises `IndexError` or `KeyError`. Is this a good way of raising exceptions?

Yes, definitely.  If you want to support both index and key access, you should implement both "sequence" and "mapping" interfaces, and raise the respective exception depending on how your method is called.

The reason for this is **abstraction**: You designed your object to behave **both** as a sequence/list type that can access its content by index, and as a mapping/dictionary type that can access its content by key.  Users of your class will choose *one* of these interfaces and not care about the other.  Hence, they expect different kind of exceptions and should not need to know the implementation details of your class.

For example, if you take a generic function that can be passed lists or other objects that behave like lists like your `CollectionOfNamedItems`, the function will use the "sequence interface" that includes the **contract** that `__getitem__` will raise an `IndexError` for invalid indices.  If you raise a different kind of exception instead, you will **break that contract, limiting the use of your class**.

The same is true for the "mapping interface".

> The caller of this method would have to catch these two types of exceptions.

Actually, since both `KeyError` and `IndexError` subclass `LookupError`, a caller of your method *that does not distinguish those cases* could and should simply catch `LookupError`:

```
try:
    item = collection[id]
except LookupError:
    # Could be KeyError or IndexError, we don't care.
```

Comment: I like that explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no most Pythonic way of catching exception. It is recommended to catch most specific exception. But when you catch multiple exceptions be aware of exception hierarchy. So you have the easiest way of finding your bugs. Sometimes you don't want to catch most specific exception, but it's you who will decide what do you need for specific piece of code.